# How do I tie a Drupal template to a webform with multiple environments?

Tags: css, templates, drupal-7, drupal-webform

Disclaimer: I inherited a Drupal 7.44 site with no experience in Drupal at all.

The business is trying to make a new webform and they want it to look exactly like an existing one. After looking around I found that the webform has a template tied to it. From the docs it seems I'm supposed to create more template files with the format `webform-form-[nid].tpl.php` where `[nid]` is the webform node id.

We have multiple environments that all changes must go through - dev, test, and finally prod. Wouldn't the node id be different in every environment for newly created webforms? Also, if I want to apply the same template to multiple webforms, do I really need to make multiple identical template files?

I also found some CSS styling for the existing webform and it looks like `.webform-client-form-25 button.webform-submit` and such. That 25 is the node id. I have little CSS experience, but this feels really bad. I don't want to copy blocks of CSS, changing node ids over and over. What's the proper way to assign generic, reusable CSS classes to webforms? I saw "Custom classes" under "Manage Display" when editing the form, but it didn't seem to change the actual HTML of the form. Was I on the right track though, should I just read some docs about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right, these detailed selectors do not make sense for reusable layouts.

Each webform HTML form gets a default class of `.webform-client-form` (that's generic) and an id including the webform's nid `#webform-client-form-<nid>`.

So, you could change `#webform-client-form-25` to the class mentioned above. Please be aware, that this will affect *all* webforms then.

To set layout settings to several, but not all webforms, you need to give these webforms some class to distinguish them from the rest. Sadly, the Webform module itself doesn't provide an option to do that, but you can add a form alter hook in your theme's template.php:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $affected_forms = array('webform_client_form_25', 'webform_client_form_37', [...]);
  if (in_array($form_id, $affected_forms)) {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-custom-class';
  }
}
```

With `.my-custom-class` you can then define CSS just for the group of webform forms listed in `$affected_forms`.

As for the template files, Webform itself states:

> This file may be renamed "webform-form-[nid].tpl.php" to target a specific webform on your site. Or you can leave it "webform-form.tpl.php" to affect all webforms on your site.

So, again, it doesn't provide an option out-of-the-box, but you can create theme suggestions in your template.php by extending `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` in a page preprocess function.

Comment: Thanks, this helps! It seems like I still have to know the nid of the form ahead of time though. Is that correct? So there's no way to provide a template that can be re-used by business users for future webforms. It seems a little counter-intuitive, usually you think of a template as a generic thing that a new specific instance can be based on.

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant the CSS classes can't really be specified ahead of time. It looks like the templates CAN be made generic using theme suggestions, if I ignore the CSS or find some other way of doing it aside from the form alter hook.

Comment: Well, there are ways to circumvent the need of knowing the nid in advance, but it's not provided by Webform itself. Through the Drupal UI, you could add a select field to the webform content type in which you choose the "type" of webform. You could then create theme suggestion based on the value of that field. That way, you could create various webforms which belong to a specific type and through the theme suggestion have them use templates like `webform-form-[type].tpl.php`. So instead of checking the form id, you would check the webform type field.

Comment: Btw, I would choose a select field so you can predefine the various types. Also, in select fields, you can provide a key for each option. For example, you could have `registration` for event registration forms and `survey` for surveys. The user who creates the webform can then only choose one of the options (make the field required) and you already know that you will need a template called `webform-form-registration.tpl.php` and one called `webform-form-survey.tpl.php`. Thus all registration forms will share a layout as do all surveys.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and it sounds way better than what we have now. I'll give it a shot.